# how to hide/close current window when we navigate to next page through User Control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a user control. I am navigating a few screens from that usercontrol. That usercontrol is showing left half of each Page. On the off chance that I click any navigation key from any page, I need to hide the present Window and I need to show the new window which I as of now navigated.

Here is My code..

xaml:

```
 <UserControl x:Class="NavigationAppBarUserControl" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Name="NavigationAppBar" >

      <StackPanel Name="appBarStack" Orientation="Vertical">
          <Button x:Name="button1"
                Content="Window1"
                Click="button1_Click" />
          <Button x:Name="button2"
                Content="Window2"
                Click="button2_Click" />           
     </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

code.cs:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 obj1 = new Window1 ();
        obj1.Show(); 
    }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 obj2 = new Window2 ();
        obj2.Show(); 
    }
```

It is navigating to the comparing screen. Be that as it may, I can't hide the present window. Since the usercontrol does not know which screen we are presently right now. I am demonstrating this user control in all pages (left side). Any offer assistance?

Note: 
In button click, I just included two Click for test. Progressively, I will have such a variety of screens. At that point, how might I close the CURRENT window?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 obj1 = new Window1 ();
        obj1.Show(); 
        CloseWindow(typeof(Window2));
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window2 obj2 = new Window2 ();
    obj2.Show(); 
    CloseWindow(typeof(Window1));
}

   void CloseWindow(Type type)
    {
        var window = App.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(w =>w.GetType()== type);
        if (window != null)
            window.Close();
    }
```

Comment: its an user control. Not a Window to close.. Please read the question again. I am unable to set this.close()

Comment: Collapse the Visibility

Comment: The user control doesn't know which screen we are now. So i dont want to set a Hardcode name of the screen as you mentioned.

Comment: I updated the answer you can check for the Visibility , and close all the Windows except the one which has UserControl and the one just showed.

Comment: Inside the Method CloseWindow(Window window) you are passing window. and again you are assigning the same name var window. I have changed the name and tried. but its not working. could you please recheck your code again?

Comment: please understand the question. In button click, i only added two Click for sample. in real time i will have so many screens. By that time, how can i close the CURRENT window? you added the Window1 in Window2 click event, Window2 in Window1 click event.. How can i identify which is current screen?